# invalid syntax def python 3.5.2

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please help I cannot figure out the problem with this. I am trying to PixelSearch. Using Python 3.5.2 and when trying to run it from Shell it comes up with syntax error on def.

```
import ImageGrab
import os
import time
import win32api, win32con


# Globals
# ------------------

x_pad = 464
y_pad = 244

def screenGrab():
    box = (x_pad+1, y_pad+1, x_pad+639, y_pad+477)
    im = ImageGrab.grab(box)
    im.save(os.getcwd() + '\\full_snap__' + str(int(time.time())) +
('.png', 'PNG')

def leftClick():
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
    time.sleep(.1)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)
    print ("Click.") #completely optional. But nice for debugging purposes.

def leftDown():
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
    time.sleep(.1)
    print ('left Down')

def leftUp():
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)
    time.sleep(.1)
    print ('left release')


def mousePos(cord):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x_pad + cord[0], y_pad + cord[1])

def get_cords():
    x,y = win32api.GetCursorPos():
    x = x - x_pad
    y = y - y_pad
    print (x,y)

def main():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am new to programming so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: please provide the error message

Comment: Which `def`? What is the exact message?

Comment: Definitely a missing closing parenthesis here: `SetCursorPos((x_pad + cord[0], y_pad + cord[1])`. This will manifest as a syntax error in the next line (the `def`).

Comment: Is `('.png', 'PNG')` really on a line by itself and does it have a missing paranthesis too?

Comment: You should be giving us a traceback, though. We shouldn't scan through your code looking for syntax errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
win32api.SetCursorPos((x_pad + cord[0], y_pad + cord[1])
```

is missing a closing parenthesis

```
x,y = win32api.GetCursorPos():
```

has a superfluous colon